# Merging multiple sorted arrays using min heap

Tags: c++

Looking to implement a function to merge multiple sorted arrays (of the same size) using STL's min heap. Here's what I have so far:

```
struct node{
    int element; // the actual element that is being stored
    int index; // array index from where the element was taken
    int next; // next index
    node(int x, int y, int z){
        element = x;
        index = y;
        next = x;
    }
    bool operator<( const node & d ) const {
        return element < d.element;
    }
};
void multiway_merge(vector<vector<int> >& input_lists, vector<int>& output_list){
   // n represents the number of unordered sublists and m is the number of integers comprising each sublist
    size_t n = input_lists.size();
    size_t m = input_lists[0].size();
    int element;
    vector<node> heap;
    heap.reserve(m);


    // loading first element of each sub-array into heap: (believe is correct)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        node current(input_lists[i][0], i, 1);
        heap.push_back(current);
    }
    make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());

    for(int j = 0; j < (n*m); j++){
        node root = heap[0];
        output_list[j] = root.element;
        if(root.next < m){ // if the next element isn't bigger than the array itself...
            root.element = input_lists[root.index][root.next];
            root.next += 1;
        }
        else root.element = INT_MAX; // problem is here
    heap[0] = root;
    make_heap(heap.begin(), heap.end());
    }
}
```

My output is generally one of the inputted numbers and then 2147483647 (INT_MAX) for the rest of the output. I commented where/why this happens above, but overall I'm very confused on how to move within the for loop to the next element and continue going through the vectors to add more elements to the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use min heap? You could merge the arrays in with much less code.

Comment: @Beta I believe it's for time complexity reasons. My professor mentioned that using min heap results in a worst case on O(mlogn). Either way, it's a requirement.

Comment: Fair enough. It would help if you gave us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How this question is generally supposed to be done is maintain `n` indices in the heap, each one representing the respective heads of the `n` arrays. Pass a predicate to `make_heap` to "heapify" it's elements based on the values at those indices. Once you pop the index of the head of the array having least value, increment this index and push it back into the heap again. I don't understand the need to make a node here.

Comment: merging two sorted arrays should be O(n) and is already implemented in the standard library. Ah multiple. I'll look at yours in a bit.

Comment: What's all this node stuff? Put everything in the heap, then pull it out. The heap will handle sorting. You said they were pre-sorted, but the comments say they are not sorted. You do NOT know how many integers are in each sublist (you only look at the first one). Needs a test case in the question so we can run it. Missing some includes. You can't assign to output_list -- use push_back or an appender.